# How to find out who funded a study / research?

Tags: discussion

It has been proven that source of funding can have an influence on the results of a research.

When we check for researches, for example through pubmed database, how can we check the source of funding ? (And check for possible financial conflict of interest ? )

Comment: This seems like it would be better-suited for meta.

Comment: Funding and other issues are often described in a paragraph near the end of reports.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on how to apply skepticism.

Comment: I didn't know asking how to apply skepticism was off-topic in the [skeptics] stackechange, but if it is, please consider moving the thread to a better location instead of just closing it.

Comment: Maybe you can ask at [academia.se]